# when you install a githup repo using jspm how to tell it what zip release to get or instead to clone repo

Tags: jspm

1) Does it clone the repo or does it pull from releases?   From what I can tell it is pulling from releases.

2) Can this be overriden via options in the same way you specify @version for a specific version. ie I want to pull a specific zip from a release branch or just clone the repo

The reason I am asking is that lets take https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/releases look at v 0.96.0, you can see it has 4 different release zip files, how does jspm know which one to get?

I was starting to write an override for materialize and add it to the jspm registry but I ran into a problem, for me I want the whole repo as it also contains the sass files in addition to the css and js, but the way jspm current installs materialize if you use this command `jspm install materialize=github:dogfalo/materialize@0.96.0` it installs materialize-v0.96.0.zip release which does not contain the sass files rather the source code zip is what I would like or a clone of the repo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just read on gitter that you can specify master when you install JSPM

For example:

```
jspm install materialize=github:Dogfalo/materialize@master
```

or for a registry package:

```
jspm install bootstrap-material@master
```